# Photoshop - How to properly apply a Gradient Map to a Brush in a layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, gradient, brush, blend-modes

I have a this Watercolor brush and painted over a transparent layer

[image]

Then I add a Gradient Map to have the desired colors in the Watercolor

[image]

But when I try to clipping mask the Gradient Map to the watercolor layer it doesn't get the previous colors, they change

[image]

Even if I set a black gackground it doesn't get my desired colors

[image]

What I need is get my desired colors without the gradient back there, since it only works when the Gradient Map is applied in general (over all layers)

[image]

This is driven me crazy, I've tried a lot of differents combinations of blend modes and no results.

Is there a propper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding a **Gradient Overlay Effect** to the brush layer?:

[image: gradient effect]

Maybe the watercolor brush you are using comes with a certain type of transparency, because it does not happen to me

[image: brush]

Comment: ok, I tried this but it doesn't get me the little details that im after, it doesnt get me my desired colors, yeah maybe is an issue with the watercolor but I'll be trying, thanks anyway

Comment: @Angel If you want the colors to get more saturated just select the brush layer and hit Ctrl+J a few times until you like it. This would make few copies of the layer, therefore increasing the opacity. Then you can select all of the copies, Group them Ctrl+G and then apply the Gradient map to the group.

Answer (score 0):

you first need to clear the background pixels (destructive editing not layer mask) from your watercolour sample before you make the brush. The gradient map is the going to use the tonal range of the remaining detail to map the gradient over.